# Why does jQuery Validate "remote:" validation require a function to set data values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

In the jQuery Validate docs it shows an example of using a remote validation call to pass additional values to server side validation script/resource:

> http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#code

Here's the sample code:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: {
        url: "check-email.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
          username: function() {
            return $("#username").val();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Why do I need to use a function to set the `username` data parameter?:

```
username: function() {
  return $("#username").val();
}
```

rather than just:

```
username: $("#username").val()
```

I've tried both methods and sure enough the second method doesn't assign `username:` a value.

I did set a breakpoint in the jQuery Validate code in the `remote` method function:

```
remote: function(value, element, param) {
    ...
}
```

to try and understand what is happening here, but I am really none-the-wiser.

Comment: Isn't `validate(cfg)` called very early, only to set up the rules (as opposed to the time validation is actually performed)? If so, that field probably doesn't have any value at the time this config object is evaluated.

Comment: Is the `;` in the second example a typo?

Comment: Putting a semi-colon inside of an object literal syntax as in `data: { username: $("#username").val(); }` returns a syntax error, but you'd probably have noticed if that was the case.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - yes, apologies that was a typo on my part when writing up the question.

Comment: As @DCoder said, storing a `function` object will execute it and return the element's current value to the ajax data every time the validation is executed, while storing a `string` will probably be stored as the initial value of when you call the `.validate`.

Comment: @DCoder - if you want to stick that in an answer then I'll accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`jQuery.fn.validate(config)`](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/jquery.validate.js) is used to *set up* the validation rules, not actually perform validation. The entire `{rules: /* */ }` object is evaluated exactly when that happens.

---

If you include

```
$('#username').val()
```

in the rules object, that expression will be evaluated immediately and the element's value at that moment will be saved.

---

If you instead pass

```
function() { 
  return $('#username').val(); 
}
```

as the value, this function will be evaluated when the [`remote` validator](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/jquery.validate.js#L1006) is invoked and the AJAX call is made, when [`jQuery.param`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L591) flattens the `data` property into a string.

Note that this validator merges its entire config object into every AJAX call it makes, so all other options acceptable in the normal ajax settings object can be set this way, not just `data`.