# jQuery .Validate() Remote sucess function and message

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii, jquery-validate

I need to validate an email field using the jQuery.Validate() plugin it has a "Remote" method which we have to post to a server and server needs to return true or false, Instead of using the traditional way(adding a function on the server to return true or false), I need to get json response from the server and on success run a function to decide where to return true or false...

Here is what the response from the server looks like (I'm using the Yii ajax form validation)

```
{
   "zipcode":[
      "Zipcode cannot be blank."
   ],
   "email":[
      "Email is already registered"
   ],

}
```

If email is listed on the array that means the validation had errors So I create a Remote validation rule like follows:

```
    'email': {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        remote:{
            type:"POST",
            url:url,
            dataType:'json',
            data:{'email':function(){
                $('#email').val();
            },ajax:'validate'},
            success:function(resp){

                $.each(resp,function(index,value){
                    if(index == "email")
                        return false;
                });

            }
        }
    },
```

But does not work, also I did not found anywhere where I can add the error message for remote validation, I would like to pass the array email value as the message...

Comment: What exactly doesnt work?

Comment: Change 'email':function(){
                $('#email').val();
            } to just 'email': $('#email').val()

Comment: I tried that but read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781856/why-does-jquery-validate-remote-validation-require-a-function-to-set-data-val?rq=1

Comment: I tried adding return false or return true on success function to see if it made any difference but not...

Comment: I suggest you read up on [the `remote` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/).  It's not nearly as complicated as you're making it.  The `true` and `false` are supposed to be coming from your server.  If you can't do that, then you cannot use the `remote` method.  Look into writing your own remote rule using `addMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your success function with below function :

```
dataFilter: function (data) {
                return 'false'; //Email not exist
                return 'true'; //Email already exist
            }
```

Please pass true/false value as a string.

For Display Message :

```
remote:{......},
messages:{email:'Please enter valid email', remote : "{0} is already exist"}
```

I think this will be help.